# aligning video tag and text together vertically

Tags: javascript, css

How can i make the video tag and text exactly vertical aligned one below the other, i am trying align it but not working. The text expands after the video, i need to align it

Any help is apprciated.

```html
<div class='video-container'>
  <div class='video-wrapper'>
    <video width="400" controls="controls" preload="metadata">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4#t=0.5" type="video/mp4">
</video>
    <div>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `width` for parent element

```css
.video-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class='video-container'>
  <div class='video-wrapper'>
    <video width="400" controls="controls" preload="metadata">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4#t=0.5" type="video/mp4">
</video>
    <div>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Erfan I had one doubt regarding on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70063149/event-timeline-with-animation If you can help me on this it will be really helpful, many thanks  